# Converting .o file into static library in linux and make it usable in terminal

Tags: c, linux, terminal, static-libraries, unix-ar

I  want to create a simple library and after compilation and ar command I can get resulting .a file.

Now I want to add this file as a static library and use it in terminal, I dont know if its possible. but idea is from other library named Ctypes.sh on github. that library can be used to make syscalls from terminal or bash terminal.

I like to know how I can add my mylib.a as static libary and make it usable from terminal.

the library is simple I  just want to invoke a few syscalls in linux from terminal.

I also looked into the code of ctypes.sh so my library is also be used to make some syscalls.

the reference I used above is here
https://github.com/taviso/ctypes.sh/wiki

Comment: Write a bash builtin that uses the library.

Comment: @KamilCuk what do u mean by bash builtin? do u mean add object file to /usr/bin/ and and add library to  where ever the libraries are installed

Comment: https://www.drdobbs.com/shell-corner-bash-dynamically-loadable-b/199102950?pgno=5 o this. Dynamically loadable bash builtin. You can then write a C source file to open that .o file and make syscalls. But I would just write it all as a builtin.

Comment: @KamilCuk if I create bash builtin file then then what will be its extension and where will it go in which folder so I dont need to be in specific folder to run it?

Comment: It's a shared library, as I understand it right now, `bash` calls `dlopen` on `your_builtin.so` when adding the builtin and then executes some function from the shared library. [Here it is](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/builtins/enable.def#L323). You can even compile your `.o` into `.so` and `enable` it from bash as a builtin itself. Please explain what you exactly mean by "make the static library usable in terminal". "Usable" - in what way?

Comment: @KamilCuk usable in a way that I dont have to be in any specific folder to execute my program(which contains system call) so for example my bash cursor at / and still to use command like `myprog puts hello` which is my program execution with parameters. also what is `your_builtin.so` above in ur comment, is it my bash builtin function script (which runs my program) or is it a program itself?

Comment: `that I dont have to be in any specific folder to execute my program` `PATH` variable is for that. `what is your_builtin.so above in ur commen` it's your program compiled to a shared library with proper interface.

Comment: @KamilCuk can u please let me know how can I add my program to bash builtin. its main program for example and if its library then how can I load it in bash builtin so constructor attribute function will be called and I start using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every command that you run on linux are binary file that you execute.
When you run a command like:

```
ls -a
```

it's like running:

```
./ls -a
```

Where the `./ls` is the binary and `-a` a parameter.

All the binary used in a terminale is stocked in the `bin` (included in the default `PATH`). When you run a command your terminal will check in first, in the folder to find the binary and after, he gonna check every folder in the `PATH` environement variable. If you wan't to add a specific folder to the `PATH` to use a personnal folder for different baniry (check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19062-01/sun.mgmt.ctr36/819-5418/gaznb/index.html)).

In your probleme you have a library with different function (I suppose) that you wan't to use in a terminale. Have 2 solution:

- Split your library in multiple micro programme, that you can execute in the terminale,
- Create a programme whit param to run different function.

Comment: I like to go with bash builtin. can u add something about that in answer? especially how can I create bash builtin file and enabling it

Comment: I don't know how to do bash builtin from personnal C library... sorry

Comment: I have up voted u but I am also looking something about bash builtin especially how to add c file or object (.o) file to bash builtin using enable command and use it as bash builtin if someone include that in answer then thats what I am looking for

Comment: I have accepted the answer since I am not getting any details on other thing I asked in comments

Comment: ok, if you wan't some precision ask about it in a new question with every precision as you can.